# Optimize the big value in redis for ranking with sorted sets

Tags: redis, sortedset

We are using the Redis for mobile game ranking with 5 million users, we are using sorted sets for ranking, some ranking got big value which is more than few hundred MB, and our cluster is unbalanced distributed because of that, is there a good way to optimize this. Right now, we are thinking about splitting the key with various sub-ranges of the score(1~100,101~200,201~300, etc), but that adds much complexity cause we have different rankings for a different purpose, each will have different score range. Also, it will be pretty hard to maintain and configure. Could you please help provide some guidance, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider saving in the sortedset only a "pointers" to keys that will old the real big data?

Comment: Thanks, the key is just a UUID, not much room can be saved

Comment: Do you use score of the user as sorted set score and the value as user id, then you use ZRANK to get the ranking of the user out of 5 million ?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 1):

Try to optimize the value structure. See there's any room to compress the value. Say, your sorted set used to be

"my_sorted_set":

> {"userId":"1","profileId":"123","name":"John"}--111.0(score),

> {"userId":"2","profileId":"1234","name":"Peter"}--122.0(score)

Change it to  {"u":"1","p":"123","name":"John"} --111.0(score)

Everybit can save with this amount of data

Split your sorted. Instead of splitting by score range, you can split by ranking range.
Assuming the ranking doesn't need to be accurate for most people. For example, I might care if I rank 2rd or 3rd in the game. But won't care/notice if I'm in mid-range already and my ranking dropped from  145645th to 14569th (You might as well show 145600th so it looks the same).

With this in mind, say you expect 10 million players. you would to have a 100 redis zsets, each taking about 100K players. And these zsets should spread evently across your cluster.

> zset_001 : Place of the top 100K players.

> zset_002 : Place of the  100K~200K ranking players.

and so on

You'll have a hash, saving the zset number each player belong to. For example,  Player A, id:1234,  you'll save    player_zset_hash :  {"1234","2"}, to mark this player belongs to zset_002

To check palyer A's ranking, you just add 100K with A's ranking in zset_2. So he might rank 10K +50 = 100050th of the game.  Player C who's in zset_4 ranking 101th. So he's overall ranking is 4*100K+101=4000101th.

Now assume player A made some big increase in scores, you increase his score and check his place in zset 002. Say he's ranking first in zset_002 now! **Compare his score with the last ranking member(say Player B)'s score in zset_001, if the A's score is higher than B's, swap their position. Put A in zset_001 and B in zset_002*. Maintain the player_zset_hash accordingly.

When you add new players(assuming each player has a starting score of zero, and people can only have non-negative score, and you don't remove players out of ranking), you put them to the last one of the zset, say, zset_100. Every night, you check the size of the last zset, if it's bigger than 100K, trim it and remove the extra ones to a new zset. (And of course, record all the zsets names you have somewhere)

One thing to note:  You might have zset_001 checked very frequently, so your redis-clusters reading loads becomes unevenly spread now. You can consider having each server checks the ranking once ever five seconds and cache it in the local server and provides it to visitor. Instead of hitting the redis every time a visiter needs to check the ranking.

---

****You might omit this step as well. And maintain all the zsets once every night, since ZRANK is a O(LogN) operation, not O(n). After all, you probably can tolerate some player's ranking being inaccurate for one day. Say he was 200005th, now he's supposed to be 199987th yet you marked him as 200001th.  If there are certain game operations that players scores significantly, incorporate this step into your code then. Say if Play A hits jack pot, compare his score ranking with other zsets after his score changes.*

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. One thing I did not figure out how to do it, if player A increase a large score, let's say, before in ZSET_50, now should be in ZSET 5, in that case, how to implement this?

Comment: That case, it will be moved to ZSET_49, then check its ranking if it's 1st in ZSET_49, if so, compare with ZSET_48' last element, if bigger, then swap, etc. All the way to  ZSET 5. I know, horribly inefficient. Though I don't think this, jump a 200K ranking suddenly, happens enough to affect the performance.

Comment: Concerns still pop up for me, first, if it happens occasionally, it could block with a long running Transactions which could take few seconds, which we would prefer to avoid this, we recently had an incident that related with that. Another thing is, I am thinking about worst case scenario, if 1M player has score 0,  as long as they changed that score, that could be way too crazy, each time, each new player will be SWAP 10 times to reach.

Comment: The first concern. No, it won't block this long. Write a lua script to make this atomic: " it's 1st in ZSET_49, if so, compare with ZSET_48' last element, if bigger, then swap and return 48, else return -1" , in your business code ,if you see the script return 48, then call the Lua script again for  for 47, and so on. Between the lua scripts callings, other redis commands can be executed.

Comment: The second concern, you probably need some other designs involving your business logi. For example, when each new player logs into the game for the first time, you place the player into the ZSET_1 (or whereever your first zero score player appears in zset ranking. For example, you have 150K non-zero score players, then you place the new player in ZSET_2 preemptively), since you know that he'll gain some score soon and have a ranking somewhere.

Comment: As for my first concerns, if some other clients can update the value in between, then the temporary results  for return 48 could not that valid anymore.

Comment: I agree for your second proposal

Comment: About the first concern. Have a background task saving the range of scores for each zset somewhere(probably in another zset, zsetkey_zset_number_xx, zsetscore_min_max_score_of_zset_xx). Before updating a players score, check where the players score would fall. If it's two zsets from the current zset, jump there directly and then adjust.  Instead of 48->47->46->45.  Write this in a lua script to make it atomic and it won't be too time consuming.